# How to get the resource for NIB file on MAC OSX

Tags: macos, resources, nib

Is there a tool to get all string for NIB file on MAC OSX? Right now, I have to copy it from the NIB editor. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to localize the NIB file, you can use `ibtool` from a command shell to pull out the strings:

`ibtool --export-strings-file <file>.strings <file>.nib`

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it will help, but you can drag and drop :)